# Resize images of Magento 2 doesn't work correct

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, image-resize

My product images have size is 600 x 600px. in file view.xml I have configured:

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
      <width>300</width>
      <height>366</height>
</image>
```

But the images that I get in category page is 300 x 300px, not 300 x 366px.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set new dimension to images by creating a new view.xml in your existing theme on below path:

**app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/etc/view.xml**

In this file add your code and run command in SSH.

> catalog:image:resize

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know result.

Comment: I have try this bug, my image still show size is 300 x 300 px.

Comment: Can you please check that whether you have added these dimensions 300*300  somewhere in your code. Please check once.

Comment: Yes, Because before I use another size.

Comment: could you please mention in which file you have added 300*300 and try to comment that code and add new code. So that we will be sure why we are not getting new dimensions.

Comment: I use theme Alothemes/bestpharmacy, So I add it to file app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bestpharmacy/etc/view.xml

Comment: could you please send me the view.xml screenshot. ?

Comment: Yes, http://prntscr.com/r3ab6y . Thank you!